# Programming for UPnP in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, upnp

I have an application that needs to do peer to peer connections on random ports, so I figure I need UPnP so that I can automatically have these ports forwarded and opened so that they can connect to their peers. I have yet to find a good example or tutorial on how to do UPnP and a lot of the docs for things like libupnp are not extremely helpful. So if you have any place where I can learn to program an application that can use UPnP please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to open ports on a Nat router I suggest you find a library that does it for  you: there's probably no need to learn upnp yourself.  If you're on Linux, take a look at GUPnP-IGD: https://developer.gnome.org/gupnp-igd/unstable/GUPnPSimpleIgd.html,  it's a really simple way to open ports.